# AngularJs ng-if-else binding two data-models

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I would like to know if any better way than what i am doing the following?

I need to bind two different data models based on $scope.title value. So, in the following example i crated two seprate DIVs for each value of $scope.title.

Can i do it on inside one `<div>`? Also i am not using ng-if-else here. How i can use ng-if-else in this example?

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="title == 'Add Student'">
    <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="registration.Student.FirstName" maxlength="50">
    </div>

    <div ng-if="title == 'Edit Student'">
    <input type="text" name="name"placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="student.Student.FirstName" maxlength="50">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
<div ng-init="model = (title == 'Add Student' ? registration.Student : student.Student)">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Student Name" data-ng-model="model.FirstName" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

To make this cleaner, you should move the part in `ng-init` to your service or controller, because it's best to keep logic out of your views. If you post the service or resource where your data is retrieved, I can add an example how to do that.

In my opinion, an even cleaner solution would be to refactor your app so that the student model always has the same reference, so to change `registration.Student` everywhere to `student.Student`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i understand your point here. However, as per your example, if open my row in edit mode (student.User.FirstName) it does not populate the existing value. Whereas in my code pasted in question it works absolutely fine. Can you recheck your code?

Comment: please check my above comments.

Comment: @immirza I updated the scope variable matching the change you made to your post.